# How to draw two parallel lines using GeneralPath

Tags: java, drawing, java-2d

I know that i can use `Line2D` .
But is there any way that i can draw two parallel lines using `GeneralPath` Class ?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot create parallel lines with GeneralPath.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. its possible to draw parallel line using GeneralPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible please find the below code

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    path.moveTo(10, 10);
    path.lineTo(10, 100);

    path.moveTo(100, 10);
    path.lineTo(100, 100);

    g2d.draw(path);
}
```

Comment: You can also `append(line, false)` two Line2D objects to the GeneralPath; that has the same effect.